# How can I specify 2 ok buttons in md dialog?

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

I'd like to have 2 ok buttons with custom handlers and 1 cancel button. If I try to add to [md dialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)?

```
.ok("OK#1").ok("OK#2").cancel("Cancel")
```

only the 2nd OK shows up. How can I tune it it?

Sample code:

```
               $scope.showConfirm = function(event) {
               var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
                  .title('Are you sure to delete the record?')
                  .textContent('Record will be deleted permanently.')
                  .ariaLabel('TutorialsPoint.com')
                  .targetEvent(event)
                  .ok('OK#1')
                  .ok('OK#2')
                  .cancel('Cancel');
               $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
                  $scope.status = 'Record deleted successfully!';
               }, function() {
                  $scope.status = 'You decided to keep your record.';
               });
            };
```

Comment: do you have any html relative to the md-dialog?

Comment: nope, that's the code I've got.